# Create a function that draws histograms

Tags: r, function, plot

I have my model:

```
library(ggplot2)

V <- function(c, E, HS, EC_50) E + (1 - E) / (1 + exp(HS * (c - EC_50)))

HS <- 1
log_EC50 <- log(1e-3)
E <- 0

log_c <- seq(-12, 0, by = 0.1)
df <- data.frame(log_c = log_c, response = V(log_c, E, HS, log_EC50))

ggplot(df, aes(log_c, response)) + 
  geom_line()
```

I want to create a function that will generate histogram for me.
I want this function to take into account parameter changes in the model, e.g. HS, E.
I am new to R and this forum so please help me

Comment: I can't understand how the normal and gamma distributions are related to your model

Comment: Sorry I mean 1 histogram

Comment: then you mus do `ggplot(df, aes( response)) +  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.1)`. Choose binwidth at your need.